# what system clock does System.currentTimeMillis(); use in Java on centOS

Tags: java, linux, datetime

I am running into an issue on my hadoop cluster caused by this line of code

```
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (startTime > endTime) {
            System.out.println("WARNING: Clock skew between the Oozie server host and this host detected.  Please fix this.  " +
                    "Attempting to work around...");
            // We don't know which one is wrong (relative to the RM), so to be safe, let's assume they're both wrong and add an
            // offset in both directions
```

[found here](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/sharelib/oozie/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/LauncherMain.java)

I wrote a sample java program which just prints the current time in milliseconds on the nodes.

```
public class CurrentTimeMillisExample {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

This does show that the time is different among the nodes just barely usually in milliseconds. The problem is if the node that ends the job is ahead by a few milliseconds everything with dates gets messed up. I would like to know where java is pulling time from. I use ntptime on all of these systems.

EDIT1:

Time difference examples
server1: 1579614657155 - Tuesday, January 21, 2020 8:50:57.155 AM GMT-05:00
server2: 1579614693828 - Tuesday, January 21, 2020 8:51:33.828 AM GMT-05:00
server3: 1579614693035 - Tuesday, January 21, 2020 8:51:33.035 AM GMT-05:00

So it does appear server 1 time is different enough to impact this. I still need to know where java is pulling this system time from?

Comment: "if the node that ends the job is ahead by a few seconds" but you just said they only differ "barely" by millis. As a general comment, it feels very brittle to rely on the server clock to get correct results: do you really need to?

Comment: @AndyTurner I should have said differ by milliseconds, I just edited the post and I will update with examples of time differences. Also unfortunately this is code I am using for Oozie that is the software we use for job scheduling and this is the way they designed it.

Comment: Clocks will *never* have *exactly* the same time. Even if they differ by half a nanosecond, there is a small possibility of two clocks returning different times. *Don't* rely on them having the same time. If you actually need to know the "start" time of the job, pass it as a parameter, for example.

Comment: `System.currentMillis()` fetches the current time from the system it is running on

Comment: For the record, good old Kerberos tolerates as much as 5min of clock skew between client and server (default setting). CockroachDB tolerates as much as 250ms of skew before losing its transactional guarantees. Even with atomic clocks in their Data Centers, Google has a _"bounded uncertainty of 7ms"_.